# Linear Algebra: Change of Basis question on Wiki definitions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I'm reading about change of basis and am confused with definitions on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) and less so on [this](https://imada.sdu.dk/%7Emarco/Teaching/AY2017-2018/DM559/Slides/dm559-lec8.pdf) site.  I present the definitions which are more understandable first, then follow with Wiki.  Here are the definitions which I understand:

$$
B = \{\mathbf b_1, \mathbf b_2, ..., \mathbf b_n\}
$$
where $B$ is a basis of a vector space $V$.   Then the coordinates $(\alpha_z)_{z \in I}$ of a vector $\mathbf x \in V$ using basis $B$ and field $F$ are:
$$
\phi_B : V \rightarrow F^n
$$
$$
\phi_B(\mathbf x) = [\mathbf x]_B
$$
$$
[\mathbf x]_B = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 \cr \alpha_2 \cr ... \cr \alpha_n \end{bmatrix}_B = (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)
$$
$$
\mathbf x = [\mathbf x]_S = \mathbf b_1 \alpha_1 + ... + \mathbf b_n \alpha_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf b_i \alpha_i
$$
The basis transformation matrix or vector is denoted $P_B$ and is from basis $B$ to $S$, where $S$ is the standard basis:
$$
P_B = [\mathbf b_1 \mathbf b_2 ... \mathbf b_n] = (\mathbf b_1, ..., \mathbf b_n)
$$
$$
P_B = [P]_S^B = [P]^B = [[\mathbf b_1]_S [\mathbf b_2]_S ... [\mathbf b_n]_S] = ( [\mathbf b_1]_S, ..., [\mathbf b_n]_S)
$$
$$
\mathbf x = P_B [\mathbf x]_B
$$
$$
\mathbf x = [\mathbf x]_S = [P]_S^B [\mathbf x]_B
$$
$$
[\mathbf x]_B = P_B^{-1} \mathbf x = ([P]_S^B)^{-1} \mathbf x
$$
where $\det(P_B) \ne 0$ and the *change of basis* from basis $B$ to $B'$ is as follows.

Convert from standard coordinates to coordinates in $B'$:
$$
[\mathbf x]_{B'} = P_{B'}^{-1} \mathbf x
$$

**Question** : does above appear correct?

I'm the most confused by the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) definitions and explanation.  The forms do not explicitly agree with above:

$$
\mathbf x_{old} = A \mathbf x_{new}
$$
is this form reversed?

Wiki then defines the change of basis formula as:
$$
B_{old} = (\mathbf v_1, ..., \mathbf v_n), B_{new} = (\mathbf w_1, ..., \mathbf w_j)
$$
For $j = 1, ... n$ and $w_j$'s coordinates are $a_{i,j}$ over $B_{old}$
$$
\mathbf w_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j} \mathbf v_i
$$

**Question**: Why are the coordinates $a_{i,j}$ two dimensional when they are one dimensional in earlier examples.

**Question**: Can the above form be rewritten in notation used earlier?  For instance:

$$
P_{B_{old}} = [\mathbf v_0 ... \mathbf v_n] = (\mathbf v_0, ..., \mathbf v_n)
$$
$$
\mathbf w_j = P_{B_{old}} [\mathbf w_j]_{B_{old}}
$$
$$
[\mathbf w_j]_{B_{old}} = (a_{1,j}, ..., a_{n,j})
$$

Comment: are you using "!=" to mean not equals?

Comment: i fixed that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) does above appear correct?** Yes. Combining the equations, we have $$[\mathbf x]_B = P_B^{-1} \mathbf x= P_B^{-1} P_{B'}[\mathbf x]_{B'}=R[\mathbf x]_{B'}$$

**2)** No. We have
$$
T(\mathbf x) = P_B \mathbf x=P_B P_B[\mathbf x]_B,
$$
so the correct map is $S(\mathbf x)=P_B^{-1} \mathbf x$.

**3) is this form reversed?** It is not reversed, if "old" is the standard basis and "new" is $B$, then in the other notation, the wiki equation reads
$$
\mathbf x= P_B[x]_B,
$$
which agrees with the equation derived in the first part of your question. But i think it would be less confusing if written $\mathbf x_{new}=A^{-1}\mathbf x_{old}$.

**4)** Yes, the equations are equivalent, the way you wrote is just the compact matricial form of the equation. If you are not convinced of that, i recommend doing with a 2x2 or 3x3 example.

---

Answer to EDIT:
**Why are the coordinates $a_{i,j}$ two dimensional when they are one dimensional in earlier examples? Can the above form be rewritten in notation used earlier?**

$a_{i,j}$ are just the coefficients of the linear combination of the vectors that produces $\mathbf w_j$, they are also the coordinates of $\mathbf w_j$ in the old basis, as you noticed. This equation is equivalent to
$$
\mathbf w_j=P_{B_{old}}\mathbf [\mathbf w_j]_{B_{old}},
$$
where $[\mathbf w_j]_{B_{old}}=(a_{1,j},\dots,a_{n,j})$, note that this equation is the same as the one in display in **3)**.     i'm not sure what you mean with "two dimensional" though.

Comment: this answers a previous version of your question, now i see your edit.

Comment: thanks, figured that.  Still reading

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb{R^2}$ as a set of ordered pairs and consider the linear transformation T that maps $(1,0)$ to $(1, 1)$ and $(0,1)$ to itself. We interpret the ordered pair $(1,1)$ and $(0, 1)$ as vectors using the *standard basis*.  We have

$T( (1,0 )) = (1, 1)$

Now think of the domain of $T$ as coordinates using the basis $ (1,1)$ and $(0,1)$. Thus $T$ is telling you how to interpret the meaning of the new coordinates $(1,0)$ in terms of the *standard basis*.  For purposes of your questions think of the standard basis as the *old basis*.  So we see that

$T( x_{newbasis}\ \ ) = x_{oldbasis}$

Comment: Do you have any insight into the Wiki definition (provided here) for this?

Comment: @Nick:  What I posted was an attempt to explain what the Wikipedia article is talking about.   The example shows that applying the linear transformation takes vectors expressed in coordinates of the new basis into coordinates of the vector in the old basis.